# How deep should my grout removal go?

Tags: bathroom, removal, grout, ceramic-tile

In regrouting a bathroom, how deep should I go to remove the old grout?
Should I go all the way the depth of the tile or will stopping at some shorter depth be just as effective in letting the new grout adhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the best results you should remove down to a depth halfway so that the new grout can bind to the original grout and to the edges of the tile.  Removing too little will not last long since the new grout will separate.  I find the best way to remove the grout is to use a dremel with an attachment that will remove the grout.  see link to video.

[Dremel Grout Removal](https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=48&v=7dgFWflRCKA)

Answer (score -2):

remove about 1/8".. should be fine